# Resizing widget cause widgets area to blackout when doing Customer opengl rendering in QT

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

For legacy reasons I have to do opengl rendering in Qt without QGLWidgets and QGLContext. I did some tests in a simple qt project first:

In mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    void mouseReleaseEvent (QMouseEvent * event );
    void mousePressEvent (QMouseEvent * event );
    QPoint m_DownPoint;
    QPaintEngine* paintEngine()const;
    bool event(QEvent * evt);
    void DrawView();
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * evt);    
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

mianwindow.cpp:
All OpenGL configuration and drawing commands are in  drawView function including swapBuffers().

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    MainWindow::paintEngine();
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);    
}

void MainWindow ::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    DrawView();
    QMainWindow::paintEvent(event);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    QPoint point = QPoint(event->pos().x(),event->pos().y());
    int dx, dy;
    if(event->button()== Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        dx = point.x() - m_DownPoint.x();
        dy = point.y() - m_DownPoint.y();
    }
    DrawView();
}

QPaintEngine* MainWindow::paintEngine() const
{
    return NULL;
}

void MainWindow::DrawView()
{
    HDC hdc = getDC();
    // m_pView->DrawView is a call to main opengl rendering function, which accepts a HDC .
    m_pView->DrawView((_HDC)hdc);
    releaseDC( hdc);
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * evt)
{
    QSize size = evt->size();
    SetViewSize(size.width(), size.height());
    DrawView();
}    

bool MainWindow::event(QEvent * evt)
{
    if (evt->type() == QEvent::Paint)
    {
 // The follwing line is commented out to avoid flickering 
//      bool result = QMainWindow::event(evt);
        DrawView();
        return true;
    }
    else if (evt->type() == QEvent::UpdateRequest)
    {
// The follwing line is commented out to avoid flickering 
//      bool result = QMainWindow::event(evt);
        DrawView();
        return true;
    }
    return QMainWindow::event(evt);
}


void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    QPoint point = QPoint(event->pos().x(),event->pos().y());
    if(event->button()== Qt::LeftButton)
    {
            m_DownPoint = point;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I drag with a mouse to resize the widgets, the widgets area is blacked out, I can see the opengl rendered image flashes, but black out instantly. I steped into qt src code and find out that the reziseEvent was sent and my Drawview is called when a resize occurs, but after that Qt did a syncbackingstore function call somehow made the widgets black.

Newbie to Qt, any advices are welcome. Qt Version 4.8.5

EDIT: paintEvent() will not be called. It remains in the code because I used to call this->update() in MouseRelease or Resize event handling functions which caused flickering in the main widget.

Comment: I don't know Qt at all, but are you sure that you need to call `DrawView()` in all these different places? I would normally expect a framework of this kind to call the redraw method whenever it needs a redraw. In the resize method, you would then only update that state that depends on the window size, but not do any drawing.